# What feature of C++ lets template classes refer to themselves without template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

Given:

```
template <typename T>
class C {
    C & operator ++ () { ... }
};
```

Why/how is `C` allowed to declare variables and functions of type `C` rather than being required to name `C<T>`?  I had not really thought about it before working on a template with many parameters that would make spelling out the "self type" inconvenient.

Are there any quirks of this I should know about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `[n3290: 14.6.1/1]:` Like normal (non-template) classes, **class
>   templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9)**. The
>   injected-class-name can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*.
>   When it is used with a *template-argument-list*, as a
>   *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter*, or as the final identifier in the *elaborated-type-specifier* of a friend class
>   template declaration, it refers to the class template itself.
>   Otherwise, **it is equivalent to the *template-name* followed by the
>   *template-parameters* of the class template enclosed in `<>`.**

Ostensibly, it's merely a convenience feature.

Comment: Amazing that two people upvoted this whilst I'd quoted the wrong passage ;-) The power of quoting the standard -- _any_ part of the standard, evidently -- cannot be denied!

Comment: Aha, the concept I was missing was *injected-class-name*.  Thanks!

Comment: in c++11 , class name is not injected , so this will cause error i think

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: The above quote is from C++11, and it says "class templates have an `injected-class-name`". [This testcase](http://www.ideone.com/XcpmM) is not a total proof in that I don't trust implementations to "fully" follow the C++11 language rules yet, but I think it's certainly good enough.

Comment: please give look to this : http://www.ideone.com/wAcHv , that's why i had said that.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: That appears to compile... perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

It's just syntactic sugar.

It is convenient to not have to change the signatures of your methods if you have to change the template parameters.

Answer (score 2):

> Why/how is C allowed to declare variables and functions of type C rather than being required to name C?

It's just specified like this. The name of the template is injected in its body and means the actual type (with arguments).

> Are there any quirks of this I should know about?

Nothing serious. You just have to remember this doesn't work for base classes, so to do CRTP, you have to do

```
template <class T>
class A : public Base<A<T> > // not Base<A>
```

Comment: Except if `Base` expects a template template parameter. ;)

Comment: @Xeo: yes, but in CRTP, the base class expect the derived type.

Comment: One does not exclude the other.