# how to typedef a class name within its class

Tags: c++

Which of the following syntaxes is preferred or is legally correct:

```
template< class T >
struct S
{
    typedef std::vector< S       > V;
//  typedef std::vector< S< T >  > V;
```

Visual C++ and gcc accept either but C++Builder XE3 reports a "E2299 Cannot generate template specialization" error on the first.

Answer (score 7):

Both are correct; the class name is *injected* into the scope of the class: [What feature of C++ lets template classes refer to themselves without template arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031823/what-feature-of-c-lets-template-classes-refer-to-themselves-without-template-a)

The feature is used occasionally; for example, the Standard uses it in its specification of the Standard library, for conciseness. You might consider avoiding it in your own code for the sake of clarity.

Comment: I'm fairly sure they do use it in, e.g., specification of `shared_ptr`: `shared_ptr& operator=(const shared_ptr& r) noexcept;`.