# Using template name without parameters

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
template <typename A>
class templatedclass {
    public:
    using type = templatedclass;
};

template <typename A>
class sinkstuff {
    public:
    void print() {
        cout << "generic sinkstuff";
    }
};
template <typename A>
class sinkstuff <templatedclass<A>> {
    public:
    void print() {
        cout << "partiallyspecialized sinkstuff";
    }
};

template <typename NtoA>
struct pass_parameter : sinkstuff<typename templatedclass<NtoA>::type> {}; 


int main() {
  pass_parameter<int> obj;
  obj.print();
  cout << is_same<templatedclass<int>, typename templatedclass<int>::type>::value; // 1, yes
}
```

I always thought the "using directive" was a typedef on steroids. How come I can use "`templatedclass<int>::type`" without specifying the parameter again, i.e. "`templatedclass<int>::type<int>`" ?

Isn't "using type = templatedclass" just a textual substitution? Am I missing something?

Comment: Nothing except macros are "just a textual substitution"!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25549652

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8031823

Comment: @dyp Definitely not duplicates but, yes, related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of a class is "injected" into the class, this is called the *injected-class-name*. It is similar to:

```
class my_class_name
{
public:
    typedef ::my_class_name my_class_name;
};
```

(But this of course doesn't compile, a class may not have a manually declared member of the same name as the class.)

Class templates also have an injected-class-name, and it can be used to refer to the class template itself, or the current specialization (including the current template arguments), depending on the context:

[temp.local]/1

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an **injected-class-name**. The injected-class-name can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*. When it is used with a *template-argument-list*, as a *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter*, or as the final identifier in the *elaborated-type-specifier* of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself. **Otherwise, it is equivalent
>   to the *template-name* followed by the *template-parameters* of the class template enclosed in `<>`**.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't have anything to do with the `using` directive. Within the definition of `A<T>` (and the `using` directive is in that scope), saying `A` is the same as saying `A<T>`.

It's the same reason you may write:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
   void foo(const A&);
};
```

instead of

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
   void foo(const A<T>&);
};
```

For more information, search for "*injected-class-name*".