# C++ class template copy contructor return type

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have declared `operator=` like this:

```
HashTable& operator=(const HashTable& aTable);
```

And I'm defining it outside the class the following way:

```
template <typename HashElement>
HashTable& HashTable<HashElement>::operator=(const HashTable& aTable)
{
    /*Do the copy thing*/
    return *this;
}
```

I'd expect it to compile with the following code:

```
HashTable<EngWord> hashTable;
HashTable<EngWord> hashTableA;
hashTableA = hashTable;
```

But the compiler doesn't like the signature of the definition. The error message is:

```
HashTable: suer of class template requires template argument list
HashTable<HashElement>::operation=': unable to match function definition or an existing declaration
```

On what I've seen on the internet it should be the way I've written. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a template argument list to the return type, as the error message says:

```
HashTable<HashElement>& HashTable<HashElement>::operator=(const HashTable& aTable)
```

The template argument list is not needed for the parameter, because the compiler already knows you're  defining `HashTable<HashElement>::operator=`, in which you can use the [injected-class-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031823/what-feature-of-c-lets-template-classes-refer-to-themselves-without-template-a).

The same holds for declaring the `operator=` inside the class template definition. You can omit the return type template arguments there, but not when defining outside the class.

Comment: Another option would be to use trailing return type